# Use javascript variable in Zoho chat widget?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, variables, zoho

I've worked on this for days and made little progress because I suck at javascript.

Goal: Create a wp plugin that allows choosing an alternate chat department for each web page, or use the default chat dept for the domain. I can do all of this with php in my plugin, BUT... all of my Wordpress websites are using Zoho SalesIQ plugin. I cannot disable this plugin, so instead I must edit the chat widget javascript that's in the plugin settings, so NO PHP. Yuck.

Much research lead me to a potential solution - I've inserted custom meta tags into the head that will hold the correct data to insert into the javascript. But that's where I get lost - how do I replace these two values in the zoho javascript with the content from the custom meta tags?

```
<meta name='my_zoho_widgetcode' content='123456789' />
<meta name='my_zoho_deptcode' content='deptA' />

<script id="zsiqchat">
    var $zoho=$zoho || {};
    $zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {
        widgetcode: "GET-WIDGETCODE-FROM-META-TAG", 
        values:{},
        ready:function(){}
    };
    var d=document;
    s=d.createElement("script");
    s.type="text/javascript";
    s.id="zsiqscript";
    s.defer=true;
    s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget?plugin_source=wordpress";
    t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);
    $zoho.salesiq.ready=function() {
        $zoho.salesiq.chat.department("GET-DEPT-FROM-META-TAG"); 
    };
</script>
```

I managed to get it to work this way, but it's going to require a lot of IF conditions (shortened here), so I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="zsiqchat">
    var zoho_meta_widgetcode = document.querySelector('meta[name="zoho_widgetcode"]').content;
    var zoho_meta_deptcode = document.querySelector('meta[name="zoho_deptcode"]').content;
    var $zoho=$zoho || {};
    if (zoho_meta_widgetcode === '123456789') {
        $zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {
        widgetcode:"123456789",
        values:{},ready:function(){}
        };
    }
    if (zoho_meta_widgetcode === '') {
        $zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {
        widgetcode:"000000000",
        values:{},ready:function(){}
        };
    }
    var d=document;
    s=d.createElement("script");
    s.type="text/javascript";
    s.id="zsiqscript";
    s.defer=true;
    s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget?plugin_source=wordpress";
    t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);
    $zoho.salesiq.ready=function()
    {
        if (zoho_meta_deptcode === 'deptA') {
            $zoho.salesiq.chat.department(["deptA"]); 
        }
        if (zoho_meta_deptcode === '') {
            $zoho.salesiq.chat.department(["Default"]); 
        }
    };
</script>
```

UPDATE: I've learned that the SalesIQ WP plugin will allow me to make some changes to the code but not other changes. This caused me so much grief I ended up disabling that plugin and inserting my own code via my plugin.